# Strange divison in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, web, division

I've got this script to calculate how much you can get with the amount you are donating.

```
$(function() {
    var ovalue = 65;
    var kann = 1;
    $("#slider").slider({
        value: ovalue,
        min: 65,
        max: 650,
        step: 65,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value + " Euro");
            kann = ($("#slider").slider("option", "value") / ovalue >> 0);
            $("#kann").val(kann);
        }
    })
});
```

the variable kann represents the amount you can get.

At first, **kann** gets 1 as result because 65/65 is 1. If I move the slider **kann** should be 2. But 130/65 still is one, although the euro amount changes to 130€. 195€ is 2, etc.

If I am at 195€ and I go back to 130€ **kann** isn't 1 anymore (which is also false) but **kann** becomes 3...really? :)

Comment: no such thing as no floating point in js, js has no integer type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ui.value` http://jsfiddle.net/vXzp9/

`.slider("option", "value")` [is always one step behind and is only set *after* `"slide"` event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js#L331).